# "mount: / is busy" when trying to mount as read-only so that I can run zerofree

Tags: ubuntu, mount, virtualbox

I am trying to run `zerofree` on Ubuntu 11.04 so that I can compact the VirtualBox vdi image using:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd Ubuntu.vdi --compact
```

In order to run `zerofree` the disk image has be mounted as read-only. I'm following [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=908128) which says to use this to remount as read-only from the recovery mode (Drop to root shell prompt):

```
mount -n -o remount,ro -t ext2 /dev/sda1 /
```

But when I do this I get the error:

```
mount: / is busy
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

**Follow up**: Following Jari's answer and [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&p=106422#p145104) by running these commands resolves the issue.

```
service rsyslog stop
service network-manager stop
killall dhclient
```

Comment: The man page for zerofree suggests running `telinit 1` and that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Some processes are keeping files open for writing. These could be, for example, programs that write logs, like `rsyslogd`, networking tools, like `dhclient`or something else. Shutting these down one by one and trying the remount might work.

You can find processes that use certain files by using the program `fuser`. For example, `fuser -v -m /` will return a list of processes. However, I am not sure if it is one of these which keeps the file system busy.

Comment: The processes that have files open in write mode will have capital `F` in the access flags in the `fuser` output.

Comment: Appending a ` 2>&1 | grep F` to the `fuser` command would be a good inclusion to this answer, as suggested by @JanHudec. It just did the trick to me.

Answer (score 32):

Improving Peter answer:

I could not kill processes that uses my mount point.
So, I did this:

- Edit `/etc/fstab` to starts in read-only in next boot. Ex: `/dev/sda1 / ext2 ro 0 1`
- Reboot and open a shell (Host Key + F2, for instance)
- Run zerofree

To "recover" your system:

- Mount with read-write option: `$ mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1`
- Edit `/etc/fstab` again, restoring your original value

Extra: if necessary open *recovery mode* in any step:

- Reboot
- Hold shift while VM is loading
- Advanced Options > Kernel option with Recovery Mode > Drop to Root Shell Prompt

Comment: Captain Obvious wants to add: Make sure you install zerofree BEFORE you reboot in ro mode

Comment: using "Drop to Root Shell Prompt" and zerofree :filesystem mounted rw. But I had no problem in other VM

Comment: This only worked for me when the `/dev/sda1 / ext2 ro 0 1` entry was at the top of the list. When I first put it as the last entry, I still had the mount point busy error.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Windows 10 host, Ubuntu 22 guest. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 27):

You can only remount the filesystem read-only if there is no process that has a file open for writing. Run `lsof /` to see what processes have files open on the root filesystem. Files open for writing will be indicated in the `FD` column. You can filter these with

```
lsof / | awk '$4 ~ /[0-9].*w/'
```

To filter the process IDs automatically, parse the output of `lsof -F pa`:

```
lsof -F pa /home | awk '/^p/ {pid = substr($0, 2)} /^a.*w/ {print pid}'
```

Comment: Tried with this solution, still busy, might becoz some resource can't show with this way.  After stop some running services, can remount the fs as read only.

Comment: I closed all processes that had a file open for reading, writing or both (`u`) and it still says busy.

Comment: worked for me on debian 10, it told me to kill atop and rsyslog, i did, then i could mount it ro :)

Answer (score 12):

If you use systemd then disk writes are stopped by stopping systemd-journald.

```
# systemctl stop systemd-journald.socket
# systemctl stop systemd-journald.service
# mount -o ro,remount /
```

Comment: For me both units restart immediately.

Comment: worked for me in "Advanced Options > Kernel option with Recovery Mode > Drop to Root Shell Prompt"

Answer (score 9):

There are sometimes so many processes keeping the mount busy, that it might be easier to simply reboot with the mount read-only.

Change the entry for the root filesystem in `/etc/fstab`, for example:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext2 relatime,rw,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

becomes:

```
/dev/sda1 / ext2 noatime,ro 0 1
```

On reboot, the filesystem will be mounted read-only, so you can run `zerofree` on it.

When you're finished, remount the filesystem read/write again (`mount -o remount,rw /`) and undo your changes to `/etc/fstab`.

Inspired by https://wiki.debian.org/ReadonlyRoot#Enable_readonly_root

Comment: Great! FYI, I used just this `/dev/sda1 / ext2 ro 0 1` and I could boot in readonly mode.

Answer (score 9):

#### Entering Un*x like GNU/Linux in *Single User Mode*

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-user_mode):

> [Single-user mode is a mode in which a multiuser computer operating system boots into a ***single superuser***. It is mainly used for **maintenance** of multi-user environments such as network servers. Some tasks may require **exclusive access** to shared resources, for example running `fsck` ...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-user_mode)

First, my goal was to *reduce* my `/` (*`ROOT`*) partition in order to add another one on same disk.

0. From running session once everything cleaned and backuped:

   ```
   init 1
   ```

   My desktop go away and I'm now on *Linux console*...

   ```
   ...
   Give root password for maintenance or press CTRL+D to continue
   TheRootPassword_SomethingLike1234
   ```
1. Ok, from now, I'm in *theorically single-user mode*, but `ps ax` show a lot of other process!!

   Killing them all tis not really possible, or dangerous... ( `kill 1` is forbiden... I don't have time to play [psdoom](http://psdoom.sourceforge.net/) :-)

   The only thing I can do is a ***`System Request`***, for this, I know two ways: (see *`Documentation/sysrq.txt`* file in kernel docs):
2. Now, trying to mount `/` in *read-only* mode:

   ```
   mount -o remount,ro /
   mount: / is busy
   ```

   If you seem unable to re-mount *root* filesytem in read-only mode politely, you could ask more severely:
3. first using ***`magic SysRq key`*** keyboard kernel trap:

   - **hold** down <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, **and maintain** them pressed,
   - hit <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> just once, but **don't release <kbd>AltGr</kbd>**,
   - hit <kbd>s</kbd> just once, this will send *`Emergency sync`* request to kernel and
   - hit <kbd>u</kbd>, this will send *`Umount all`* request, this will remount all mounted filesystems read-only,
   - then **now**, you could **release <kbd>AltGr</kbd>**
4. Or by command line:

   ```
       echo s >/proc/sysrq-trigger
       echo u >/proc/sysrq-trigger
   ```

   I could check by testing to create a file:

   ```
       touch /dummyfile
       touch: cannot touch '/dummyfile': Read-only file system
   ```
5. Then now, I could use tools on my root partition!

   ```
   fsck -fC0 /dev/sda2
   ```

   Like any other tools: `zerofree`, `partclone`, `resize2fs` (even to shrink partition, but for this, I had to use a `loop` device...), etc...

   Saving my whole *root* partition to a USB device, with `zstd` compression and creating a `sha1sum` controle file simultaneously:

   ```
   mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
   mkdir /media/usb/save-$HOSTNAME-$(date +%F)
   cd /media/usb/save-$HOSTNAME-$(date +%F) || exit 1
   partclone.ext4 -c -s /dev/sda2 -O >(
       zstd | tee sda2.ext.zst |
           sha1sum |
           sed 's/-$/sda2.ext.zst' >> sha1sums.txt
       ) -N -L sda2.log
   ```
6. Then **`reboot`!!**.

   Don't ever try to return in multi-user mode without rebooting completely!!

Comment: Note: In fine, if my `fsck` was succesfully done, I've booted a *Live USB* in order to by able to run `resize2fs`... This *feature* is not already implemented...

Comment: My `fsck` doesn’t know `-f`; what would that do, zero unreferenced blocks?

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ: I'ts `ext2`'s `fsck` switch: ***`-f`       Force checking even if the file system seems clean.***

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ No, `zerofree` is not `fsck`!  I'd never used `zerofree`!  I prefer to use `partclone` which save the partition without unreferenced blocks. (or `tar` or `rsync`, for saving only files, but excluding caches and other useless files)...

Answer (score 7):

If you still can not unmount or remount your device after stopping all services and processes with open files, then there may be a swap file or swap partition keeping your device busy. This will not show up with `fuser` or `lsof`. Turn off swapping with:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

You could check beforehand and show a summary of any swap partitions or swap files with:

```
swapon -s
```

or:

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

As an alternative to using the command `sudo swapoff -a`, you might also be able to disable the swap by stopping a service or *systemd* unit. For example:

```
sudo systemctl stop dphys-swapfile
```

or:

```
sudo systemctl stop var-swap.swap
```

In my case, turning off swap was necessary, in addition to stopping any services and processes with files open for writing, so that I could remount my root partition as read only in order to run `fsck` on my root partition without rebooting. This was necessary on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 2):

## *Attach the vdi file as additional and non-system volume to another VirtualBox. There you can (re)mount it as needed and perform the zerofree.*

Let us say you want to compact the VDI disk of *VM1* (Virtual Machine 1). Then you need a second ***VM2***. That is, :

- Make sure that neither VM1 nor VM2 is running;
- From VirtualBox Manager:

  - Select VM2,
  - "Settings"->"Storage"->"Add Hard Disk":[image: "Select it as additional disk"],
  - select the vdi file of VM1, which you want to compact. Hint: Make sure that the hard disk just added to VM2 goes second in boot-order after the original disk of VM2.
  - start VM2: now you can (re)mount the volume of VM1 as additional disk for VM2, because no process are using it in VM2. Hint: First, open the volume with the folebrowser of Linux, which automatically mounts the volume. Then, use `mount -l` to see which is the `_Device_` in the command `sudo mount -o remount,ro _Device_`. In my case this was **/dev/sdb1**. So the command was (1) `sudo mount -o ro,remount /dev/sdb1` and then (2)`sudo zerofree /dev/sdb1`.

Instead of VM2 one should be able to boot from and installation disk like and **.iso image** and achieve the same BUT I have not tried it.

Comment: This sounded promising, but when I added the second VDI as SATA1 (after SATA0 for the original one) I had no extra entry in my client. `blkid` showed `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` but with the same `UUID`s.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who's just looking for a quick fix to paste into your terminal...

(Before following the commands below, make sure you have completed the other steps like `telinit 1`.)

[Found this](https://linuxexplore.com/tips-tricks/umount-a-busy-partition/):

```
fuser -mv /dev/sda1 > /tmp/sda1.pids
kill `cat /tmp/sda1.pids`
```

Commands may kill your session, but after you come back, your partition is ready to be remounted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you try to run the `mount` command in the VM. Anyway you probably have a different root partition than the author of the forum post.

Try:

```
mount -o ro,remount /
```

Which does not depend on the fs or mount option. If this does not work you can also try to determine your root fs with `grep " / " /proc/mounts` or `cat /proc/cmdline`. If your root filesystem is for example /dev/mapper/system-rootfs you can use:

```
mount -o ro,remount /dev/mapper/system-rootfs /
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue which kept me from putting my machine in read only mode. Solving the problem took me a longer than id like to admit... I believe my issue was that I left Apache-Zeppelin running and forgot about it. Make sure that you are not doing the same with another hosting type service. To solve the problem I used `fuser -kill /` to terminate all of the processes that could be causing the issue and it allowed me to go back into ro mode.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to reboot the OS and choose "recovery mode" from GRUB's boot menu. From "recovery mode", there are fewer processes running, and remounting read-only works fine.

If the system has a swap file on the root file system (rather than a swap partition), it is also necessary to temporarily switch off the swap file with `swapoff -a`.